# Trigger function that is called in onload callback of script

Tags: javascript, dom, jestjs, stenciljs

I want to test a component (written in stenciljs) and in the initial function of the component, a script is loaded and onload a function should be executed. The function is private but I want to test the logic inside this function.
Unfortunately, the onload callback is not triggered when I test the component with Jest (it is triggered fine when using it, so it is only a testing issue).
Is there a possibility to fake the "onload" event so my function is triggered inside the test?

```
//This is called inititally in the component
addScript(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}&libraries=places`).onload = () => {
  this.initialize(); // gets not called inside test
};

export const addScript = (src: string): HTMLScriptElement => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return script;
 };
```

Comment: is this about a spec or e2e test? you might just need to write an e2e test (`newE2EPage`) to get the script to load (runs in a real browser), because spec tests (with `newSpecPage`) just use a virtual browser context inside a node.js context.

Comment: alternatively, if you don't need the google maps script to work for your test, you can manually call the `initialize` method of your component (may need to expose it with the `@Method()` decorator).